# Best practice for storing external API secrets in server using AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, server, aws-lambda, web-development-server

I built an application to integrate various financial services for my company. We access brittle, old legacy-esque external API's to pull purchases and things of nature. The server should update our transaction history every morning automatically through these API's. This information is very sensitive. I want to avoid storing secrets on the server or forcing the user to input credentials. I came up with an AWS-based solution. I'd like both advice on its implementation and suggestions on feasible alternatives.

I want to use Lambda or some other AWS service to both store the keys and retrieve the necessary information. The primary server can then either access the information through an API or be sent data from AWS. This secondary server should be as secure as possible, with no SSH or remote access except through Amazon's browser interface. I'd like to use certificates to retrieve the information from this cloud server at some point, if that's the implementation I end up going with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For secrets you'd want to be looking at [Secrets Manager](https://aws.amazon.com/secrets-manager/). The contents are natively encrypted via [KMS](https://aws.amazon.com/kms/) so rest assured they'll be encrypted.

Any interaction is done via API, so it would be authenticated via IAM